# From highest to smallest loop

Tags: php

Hello i need help or how to make work loop from biggest to smallest variable.

I have 5 peoples witch have attribute speed (speed1, speed2... speed5) and i am doing a for loop witch will be 6 times and now i want inside that loop do some action on each people but its have to be from highest speed to lowest speed first one with the highest speed will go executed first then the second highest and so on

```
for($a = 0; a < 6; a++){
   // first man code 
   // second man code
   // third man code
   // 4th man code
   // 5th man code
}
```

so code will be almost the same just different values

i have attributes with name, damage, speed on each man and i want to make that man who have highest speed will go first and will be executed first and then the second highest , could someone help me with this maybe there is some function in php witch allows me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change value $a, and change ++ to --

```
  for($a = 6; $a > 0; $a--){
     // 5th man code 
     // 4th man code
     // third man code
     // second man code
     // first man code
    }
```

Comment: you make nothing with this code this loop runs 6 times anyway and there is no code witch checks speed of ppl